# Rspec How to test if a Sidekiq Job was scheduled to run at a certain time

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails, rspec-sidekiq

I have the following Worker

```
class JobBlastingWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: 'job_blasting_worker'

  def perform(job_id, action=nil)
    job = Job.find(job_id)

    JobBlastingService.new(job).call
    sidekiq_id = JobBlastingWorker.perform_in(2.minutes, job.id, 're-blast', true)
    job.sidekiq_trackers.create(sidekiq_id: sidekiq_id, worker_type: 'blast_version_update')
  end
end
```

In my rspec test, i have the following `job_blasting_worker_spec.erb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe JobBlastingWorker do
  before(:all) do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end

  describe 'perform' do
    context 'create' do
      it 'creates job schedule for next 2mins' do
        @job = create(:job)
        worker = JobBlastingWorker.new
        expect(JobBlastingWorker).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job(@job.id, 're-blast').in(2.minutes)
        worker.perform(@job.id, 'create')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I expect this to work but i realize that the sidekiq job that should be scheduled for the next 2minutes never gets created. Hence, the test fails.

How am i able to ensure that the sidekiq job actually creates for the next 2mins and the test runs successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Well...for this kind of expectation, I suggest just test the message sent to the method.

```rb
  expect(JobBlastingWorker).to have_enqueued_sidekiq_job(@job.id, 're-blast')
  expect(JobBlastingWorker).to receive(:perform_in).with(2.minutes, job.id, 're-blast', true).and_call_original
  worker = JobBlastingWorker.new
  worker.perform(@job.id, 'create')
```

Of course, if you dig really hard, I think you will finally find a way to find the active job object in the queue, for example, by using the Redis API directly.
And then you can further examine the object and get the time you set for the job to be performed.
But why? That's ActiveJob responsibility to make sure those jobs will be performed at the right time.
Finding this doesn't help you much, and this behavior should be already tested in RSpec its tests.
I think you don't need to worry about that unless it works incorrectly and you want to reproduce that situation and issue a bug.

On the other hand, the **time** you send to the method is what you should care about. You don't want someone to change it to `2.hours` by accident.
So I suggest you should test the message you send to the method.